# Using custom data type over JSON WCF

Tags: .net, json, wcf

I have a JSON WCF service. In that service, I am using custom class called `Date` (it's just like the `DateTime` structure, except it ignores time portion of `DateTime`).

Anyway, let's say I have an operation contract like this:

```
[OperationContract]
Date Test();
```

And here's the implementation:

```
public Date Test()
{
    return new Date();
}
```

The service is configured to behave as JSON service (in Service.svc I've set `Factory="System.ServiceModel.Activation.WebServiceHostFactory"`).

And here is the Date class:

```
public class Date
{
    private DateTime _internalDate;

    public Date()
    {
        _internalDate = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day);
    }

}
```

Of course, after I run this example I just get

> {}

How can I define the way I want my Date class to serialize to JSON?

Comment: As an aside, your constructor evaluates `DateTime.Now` three times. You might want to think about what it might give if it starts at "almost exactly midnight", and the date rolls over between the first and second or between the second and third evaluations...

Comment: @JonSkeet: That's just quick example, but thanks for pointing it out ;)

Comment: @L.B: I don't want to make _internalDate public. I also do not want it to serialize like DateTime - I want custom format. There must be a way to do it ...

Comment: @xx77aBs then put something public in your class

Comment: @L.B There must be another way. When DateTime gets serialized, it is turned into something like this: "\/Date(1346968800000+0200)\/". There isn't any property in DateTime with that value. I want to do the same, but of course change the format into which my class gets serialized.